# class_netgeoip causing problems

Tags: php

I’ve been using this certain software for about 2 years without any problems. Recently I uploaded a folder called class_netgeoip. This folder came with the software package, but was not installed. Now the software doesn't work. When I try to open the dashboard I got this:

```bash
Fatal error: Uncaught LogicException: Passed array does not specify an existing static method (class 'ComposerAutoloaderInitb247e8e7eb0df5b91faf7ebd591e282f' not found) in /home/black/public_html/_includes/class_netgeoip/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:0 
Stack trace: 
#0 /home/black/public_html/_includes/class_netgeoip/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(0): [obfuscated]() 
#1 /home/black/public_html/_includes/class_netgeoip/vendor/autoload.php(0): �����������������������::getLoader() 
#2 /home/black/public_html/_includes/class_geoip.php(0): unknown() 
#3 /home/black/public_html/index.php(0): require_once('/home/black/pub...') 
#4 /home/black/public_html/index.php(0): [obfuscated]() 
#5 {main} thrown in /home/black/public_html/_includes/class_netgeoip/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 0
```

So I deleted the class_netgeoip.php folder, and now I get this:

```
Warning: main(/home/black/public_html/_includes/class_netgeoip/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/black/public_html/_includes/class_geoip.php on line 0
```

Anyone know how I can fix this? I paid someone to install this package and this person is no longer available.

I deleted it expecting that everything would return to normal like it was before I uploaded it. I'm very much a novice.

I have websites on this server which still work fine, it only affects this particular application.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that deleting the class_netgeoip.php folder has caused some dependencies to break, which are required for your software to run properly.

Restore the class_netgeoip.php folder: If the class_netgeoip.php folder was part of the software package and not installed, it is possible that it was required for the software to function correctly. You should try restoring the folder from a backup if you have one or download a fresh copy of the software and copy the folder back to your server.

And run then composer update

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The software worked fine for two years, so I don't think it is required.

Comment: I can help you with solving this issue. You can contact me.

Comment: When I run composer update I get a warning "Do not to run Composer as root/superuser!", I ran it anyway and I got this message: Composer could not find a composer.json file in /root  -bash: Composer: command not found.

Comment: @Abdelouali Benkeil  Can you help me with this?

Comment: Anyone?????????